# Declaring a variable for use in a Build Process

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, tfs, build-process

I am using a custom build process template and I am trying to declare a variable that can be used to populate the default in an argument, but I'm having some problems and I think it's simply because I don't quite understand how `XAML` and the build process use variables.

For ease of explanation (because our build process is terribly complex) here is what I'm looking at:

```
Process Begin
    Run On Agent
    Initialize Variables
        If RunTests = True Then
            Establish a Connection to SQL
            Run SQL
            Run Tests
            Email User with Results
        Else
            <Do Other Things>
        End If
    Finish Build
Process End
```

I'm trying to use the XAML editor built in to VS2012 (although I'm open to switching if there's a better IDE, I have to add a lot of stuff to this template). So I'll click on the `Run On Agent` node and click on the Variables section to create a variable called `SQLServername`. This variable is supposed to be populated by the `SqlServerHostName` argument that is part of the `Build Definition`. So `SQLServername`'s default value is `SqlServerHostName`. No problem there, I think.

However, I then try to add a new argument: `ConnectionString` which defaults to `"Server=" & SQLServername & ";database=master;integrated security=sspi"`, and the compiler error:

```
SQLServername is not declared
```

Occurs. I'm sure I am misunderstanding variables and how they're used within this thing, but what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was misunderstanding the scope of the variable declaration. I simply left the ConnectionString as a string that the user can modify, which works for our purposes.